# Insert Into in mysql Case when

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, case-when

I have 2 tables and I made an inner join.

1)`car_table`

```
|car_id|  cars   |
|----- | -----   | 
|1     | Passat  |
```

2)`property_model`

```
|model_id|  p_value |
|--------|   -----  | 
|1       |   year   |
|2       |   color  |
|3       |   gear   |
```

3)`property_value`

```
|value_id| car_id| model_id| rs_value |
|--------|-----    | -----   | -----    |
|1       |   1     |   1     | 2020     |
|2       |   1     |   2     | Black    |
|3       |   1     |   3     | Manuel   |
```

I followed a way like this but the code gives an error

```
INSERT INTO property_value (model_id,rs_value)
SELECT model_id,car_id
    CASE model_id
        WHEN 1 AND car_id=1  THEN '2020' 
        WHEN 2 AND car_id=1  THEN 'Black'
        WHEN 3 AND car_id=1  THEN 'Manuel' 
      
    END
FROM property_model
```

How can php I add a new data from property_model table to property_value table?

Comment: The syntax you're using doesn't make much sense.  Why not just use three separate `INSERT`s, one for each `model_id`?

Comment: You need a `SELECT` subquery.

Comment: Do you want to insert new rows, or change the `rs_value` columns of the existing rows? Why are you joining with the table you're inserting into?

Comment: @barmar  I want to add new lines
Example: model=1 then '2020', model=2 then 'black' as

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `SELECT` query as the source of data to insert:

```
INSERT INTO property_value (model_id, rs_value)
SELECT model_id,
    CASE model_id
        WHEN 1 THEN '2020'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Black'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Automatic'
    END
FROM property_model
```

You can also use the [`ELT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_elt) function to select a value by index in the argument list.

```
INSERT INTO property_value (model_id, rs_value)
SELECT model_id, ELT(model_id, '2020', 'Black', 'Automatic')
FROM property_model
```

For your second query, I guess it should be like this:

```
INSERT INTO property_value (model_id, car_id, rs_value)
SELECT model_id, 1,
    CASE model_id
        WHEN 1 THEN '2020' 
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Black'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Manuel' 
      
    END
FROM property_model
```

Comment: Thank you so much but i am getting error.

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '

Comment: Sorry, didn't need commas in `CASE`.

Comment: Execuse me, i  just have one more question. I want to add one more column to property_value table. I edited it now, you can see it again from the table above, how can I insert data from another table into property_value table?

Comment: 1. There's no `car_id` column in `property_model`, I guess you need to join with `car_table`. 2. You need to add `car_id` to the list of columns being inserted into. 3. You need a comma between `car_id` and `CASE`.

Comment: 4. When you use `CASE columnName`, the `WHEN` clauses are just single values to compare with `columnNAme`. If you want more complicated conditions, you have to put both conditions in the `WHEN` clauses, e.g. `WHEN model_id = 1 AND car_id = 1 THEN '2020'`

Comment: ohh very very thank you much men. I'll never forget you :))